# Passando uma string criada no Windows forms para o Crystal Report

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

Eu precisava adicionar uma string criada no Windows Forms Application no Campos de Parâmetro, mostrado na primeira imagem abaixo, dentro do Crystal Report para posteriormente fazer um filtro, como na segunda imagem abaixo.

Eu gostaria de saber o que tenho que fazer ou codificar para passar a string ou se a maneira de fazer isso é de outra forma?

Eu Uso Mysql Free, Visual Studio Community 2017.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade ao certo? Já tem algum código feito? Edite a sua questão e coloque-o aí.

Comment: A dificuldade consiste em passar a string do Windows Forms para o Crystal Report para fazer um filtro eu não saberia como fazer isto por isso não tem um código.

Comment: Recomendo ler alguns tutoriais antes de começar a codificar. Aqui tem dois: [C# Crystal Reports step by step](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm) e [Create Crystal Report Step by Step Using SQL Database View](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/create-crystal-report-step-by-step-using-sql-database-view/).
Só terá que adaptar para MySQL.